# All join statements are returning Cartesian product in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hello there every body.

I'm facing a problem in MySQL.I tried all kind of possible joins (natural , inner , outer) what so ever. all of them are returning the Cartesian product for me.

I just want a natural join between two tables.

```
select * from customer natural join ProcessH;
```

I tried this query with `where clause , and join ON clause`. but I'm still receiving the Cartesian product

Comment: be helpful if you posted your entire query you tried so we can see what happened.

Comment: That's what a JOIN does, unless you have a join clause. In addition to the query, show the table definitions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NATURAL JOIN uses the common columns as join condition.

E.g., given

T1(X,Y,Z)
  T2(Y,Z,W)

will join on T1.Y = T2.Y AND T1.Z = T2.Z.

If you don't have common column names, you get the cross product.

**EDIT:**

Example:

```
create table T1(x int, y int, z int);
create table t2(y int, z int, w int);
insert into T1 values (1,2,3), (10,20,30);
insert into T2 values (2,3,4), (20,30,40);
select * from T1 natural join T2;
```

gives you

```
+------+------+------+------+
| y    | z    | x    | w    |
+------+------+------+------+
|    2 |    3 |    1 |    4 |
|   20 |   30 |   10 |   40 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

But

```
create table T3(x int, y int);
create table T4(z int, w int);
insert into T3 values (1,2), (10,20);
insert into T4 values (3,4), (30,40);
select * from T3 natural join T4;
```

gives you:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| x    | y    | z    | w    |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |    3 |    4 |
|   10 |   20 |    3 |    4 |
|    1 |    2 |   30 |   40 |
|   10 |   20 |   30 |   40 |
+------+------+------+------+
```